# Вывод сериалов php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Здравствуйте!

В поле xfields имеется название сериала.
Мне нужно вывести список сериалов, исходя из названия сериала в поле xfields.

Движок DLE.

Код:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_post`";
$result = $db->query($query);

$i=0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

    $short_name_explode = explode('|', $row['xfields']);
    $short_name_result = $short_name_explode[1];

    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `" . PREFIX . "_post` WHERE `title` LIKE '%$short_name_result%' LIMIT 1";
    $result2 = $db->query($query2);

    while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
        echo $row2['title'] . '<br><br>';
    }


    $i++;
    echo $i;
}
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема.
Выводятся сезоны по несколько раз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще-то ожидается, что это Вы скажете, в чём обнаружилась проблема и какая именно, а мы попробуем подсказать, как от неё избавиться...

Comment: Не надо на каждый пост из таблицы делать запрос к базе. Это неправильно!

Comment: Да так и понял, что в этом проблема. Как тогда поступить лучше? Не могу додуматься просто..

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию у `fetch_array` результат  `$resulttype = MYSQLI_BOTH`, то есть результирующий набор будет содержать массив, включающий атрибуты вариантов **MYSQLI_NUM** и **MYSQLI_ASSOC**.

Решение проблемы: выбрать один из вариантов и добавить его в параметр. Пример:

```
....->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

---

Ну и делать запрос к БД в цикле - это кошмар и ужас. Не надо так. Надо выбрать данные и уже с ними работать как нужно, сделав, например, доп. запрос к БД с применением `IN`. Или же использовать `JOIN` и т.д.

Comment: Можно подробнее, как сначала вытащить список сериалов из xfields, а потом с ними работать?

Comment: @E.A. не зная структуру таблиц, что конкретно находится в `xfields`, зачем ему делается explode и причем тут он - без понятия

Comment: Ну понятно же, что там идет строка вида data|data2|data3 и т.д. Вот на второй позиции название сериала. Скажите хотя бы примерно поверхностно

Comment: @E.A. `Ну понятно же` - нет не понятно. например зачем цикл? там на новой строке новые данные? а зачем? как они вообще соотносятся с данными на той же строке в таблице? почему они не в отдельной таблице? почему название сериала находится в строке на второй позиции разделенная чертой? почему название берется из этой колонки а не прилетают запросом от пользователя? так что нет - вообще не понятно